# How to create multiple mapping of one table? (jpa hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Im creating an application in spring boot. I want to have multiple entity mapping for one table.
one entity retrieve the table without any join and the other entity retrieve the table with join.

**This is the table schema:**

book : `{"id":1, "title":"math1", "author_id":1}`

author: `{"id":1, "name": "james"}`

thank you.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? It should work out of the box for the most part, though you might want to make one of the entities read-only

Answer (score 0):

Ive made it.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BookBase<T extends BookBase> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false, name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public T setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        return (T) this;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public T setTitle(String title) {
        this. title = title
        return (T) this;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Book extends BookBase<Book> {
    @Column(name = "author_id")
    private Integer authorId;

    public Integer getAuthorId() {
        return authorId;
    }

    public void setAuthorId(Integer authorId) {
        this.authorId = authorId;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table
public class BookJoinAuthor extends BookBase<BookJoinAuthor> {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

    public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthorId(Author author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table
public abstract class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false, name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public T setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        return (T) this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public T setName(String name) {
        this. name = name
        return (T) this;
    }
}
```